# Why doesn't ISNULL work with concatenated strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to run a stored procedure in SQL Server 14 and I need to concatenate a string and execute it. In that string, I want to do a select of a column if the parameter is null. But for some reason, using `ISNULL` with a concatenated string doesn't return anything except for 'Commands completed successfully'.

I have created a simple scenario:

```
declare @startdate datetime = null;
declare @sql nvarchar(1000);

set @sql = '
select isnull('''+convert(varchar,@startdate,101)+''',''Is null'')'
exec(@sql)
```

and when I run that I would like to see the 'Is null' result, but I only see the statement: 'Command completed successfully' and the current time (completion time).

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work the way that I expect it to?

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL Server 14* - are you referring to SQL Server **2014** - or do you mean SQL Server **2017** (v14.x.x.x) - please be **precise** in your asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `@startdate` is `null`. When you convert a `null` datetime value to a varchar, you get (surprise) `null`.

We now take that `null` varchar and concatenate it with the rest of the literal varchar value to assign to `@sql`. Guess what: concatenating `null` with another string also produces `null`.

**The value of the entire `@sql` for this `exec()` statement will be `null`!**

Much better practice here is to use `sq_executesql` and include your extra data as it's own variable.

Comment: Joel, Thank you for this explanation. I found it very helpful in learning why I kept getting a null value!

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing the parameter properly. You should be using `exec sp_executesql` to execute the dynamic query, and pass the parameter and its value as arguments, like so:

Consider:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000);
set @sql = N'select isnull(convert(varchar,@startdate,101), ''Is null'')'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@startdate datetime', @startdate = null
```

Note that this can be simplified to not use an intermediate variable to store the parameter:

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'select isnull(convert(varchar,@startdate,101), ''Is null'')', 
    N'@startdate datetime', 
    @startdate = null
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a19e0c07320cf25cf60be37081f54d86)** - both code blocks yield `'Is null'`.

Comment: GMB, Thank you for the code. I appreciate your time and effort to guide me.